# Counting the number of bits of a positive integer #2

Tags: python, algorithm, python-2.x

I think the running time of this should be \$O(log_{2}(n))\$:

```
def count_bits(num):
    assert num >= 0
    count = 0
    while (num != 0):
        num >>= 1
        count += 1
    return count

print count_bits(0) #0
print count_bits(2) #2
print count_bits(pow(10, 2)) #7
print count_bits(pow(10, 9)) #30
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code is neat, variables are well named, the input validation is there, etc. It's all good. The assessment of your time complexity being \$O(\log_2{n})\$ is also right.

But, is that as good as it can be? Well, your time-complexity assessment is a hint as to what's a better solution... The base-2 log is also an indication of the number of bits used. Remember, in base 2, the number of bits needed increases at the exponential of 2 as well.

As a consequence, your function could be reduced to \$O(1)\$ with:

```
import math

def count_bitx(num):
    assert num >= 0
    if num == 0:
        return 0
    return 1 + int(math.log(num, 2))
```

Note that Python 3.1 introduced the [`bit_length()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#additional-methods-on-integer-types) method, so you could do:

```
def count_bits(num):
    assert num >= 0
    return num.bit_length()
```

Comment: `math.log` is quite expensive though, so O's don't always tell you the whole truth. I guess using integer arithmetic should be faster than this code (though I might be wrong).

Comment: It is the smallest number for which it happens, and it is pretty far out, but `assert int(math.log(2**2955, 2)) == 2955` raises an `AssertionError`.

Comment: @Jaime - Hmmm.... That's a big number. I guess that's why the fix for 3.1 using bit_length is in there ;-) I think if the OP's working in that scale of things, that a newer version of python would be warranted. Out of interest, did the performance remain O(1) or did the log process start slowing down when you got up there?

Comment: The code I run was `for j in range(3000): assert int(math.log(2**j, 2)) == j`, and it completes in an eye blink, so speed doesn't seem to be a relevant concern.  It is still flaky  (and probably slower) to use floating point arithmetic for an integer operation.  [This](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.5/Objects/longobject.c#L4842) seems to be the implementation of `bit_length` in Python 3.5, and [here](https://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#IntegerLogObvious) are several other possible approaches, and none of them uses anything other than integer arithmetic.